# In java how to print chars of a string from any particular index and after reaching end of string again start from index 0 if printed not equal length

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, while-loop

Basically I have a string of numbers and that string will be dynamic in nature both content wise and length wise ex. "13579", "12345789" etc.
If the length of string is n then I want to create n strings from it.
Suppose string is "13579" then I have to create 5 Strings from it starting from different index like below:

```
13579
35791
57913
79135
91357
```

How can I do this using a generic loop which works for all the string lengths?

Can someone help?

Thank!!!

### EDIT:

Here is what I have tried

```
public class Pattern28 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= sc.nextInt();
    int i=1;
    int odd=1;
    String sNum="";
    while(i<=n) {
        int j=1;
        if(i==1) {
        while(j<=n) {
           System.out.print(odd);
         if(i==1 && j<=n) sNum=sNum.concat(Integer.toString(odd)); //to get first row numbers in string
            odd+=2;
            j++;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("im "+sNum);
    j=i-1;
    if(i!=1) {
        //  int k=i-1;
        while(j<=n) {
            System.out.print(sNum.charAt(j));
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    i++;
}
}
}
```

Stuck at last while loop. Every time I do something there I end up with "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" as index either reaches string length+ or goes in negative.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Using `substring` with a few length checks should to the trick. Nobody here will just do your homework for you if you don't show what you've tried.

Comment: I figured out a way :)

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was resolved here [Generate all rotations of a number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-rotations-of-a-number/)

```
public class Pattern28 {


        // Function to return the count of digits of n
        static int numberOfDigits(int n)
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                cnt++;
                n /= 10;
            }
            return cnt;
        }

        // Function to print the left shift numbers
        static void cal(int num)
        {
            int digits = numberOfDigits(num);
            int powTen = (int) Math.pow(10, digits - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < digits - 1; i++)
            {
                int firstDigit = num / powTen;

                // Formula to calculate left shift
                // from previous number
                int left = ((num * 10) + firstDigit) -
                        (firstDigit * powTen * 10);

                System.out.println(left + " ");

                // Update the original number
                num = left;
            }
        }

        // Driver Code
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int num = 1445;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your number ?");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            cal(n);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the first character of the string to the end, and `substring` the string at index `1`.

```java
String rotate(String string) {
    return string.substring(1) + string.substring(0, 1);
}
```

```java
String string = "13579";
do {
    System.out.println(string);
    string = rotate(string);
} while (!string.equals("13579"));
```

Output

```
13579
35791
57913
79135
91357
```

If you need all these values in a `String` array, you can use the following.

```java
String string = "13579";
String[] strings = new String[string.length()];
for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index++) {
    strings[index] = string;
    string = rotate(string);
}
```

Output of `strings`

```
[13579, 35791, 57913, 79135, 91357]
```